# NVMe drive disappears after kernel panic

Tags: linux, boot, grub, uefi

I'm working on imaging a `Dell OptiPlex Micro 3000` device with Linux (custom Yocto-based OS). Grub version 2.04. I'm using an A/B partitioning scheme and trying to get the fallback to function properly but I think I might be running into a conflict with a BIOS (UEFI) setting somewhere.

Desired result: if either boot option encounters a kernel panic, the system should fall back to the other boot option.

Actual result: if there is a kernel panic, the system reboots and then the nvme drive is gone.

The boot options are similar, except for the root drive (one points to /dev/nvme0n1p2 and one to /dev/nvme0n1p3), e.g.

```
linux /bzImage root=PARTUUID=*snip* rootwait rw oprofile.timer=1 root/dev/nvme0n1p2 rootfstype=ext4 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0 crashkernel=auto panic=5
```

With a bad bzImage, I boot with this option, a kernel panic ensues, the reboot happens after 5 seconds - and then the system boots into my Clonezilla-imaged thumb drive. I enter the Clonezilla command line and `ls /dev` and there are no nvme drives or partitions. In fact, there's no `/dev/nvme0` controller either.

If I reboot and select the boot option for my drive, I get a UEFI-looking window that says "No Hard Drive".

If I go through the UEFI menu and try to add the boot option for my drive, the device isn't listed.

Here is the odd part though. If I:

1. kernel panic
2. reboot
3. enter UEFI settings
4. quit (no changes or modifications of any sort, no save)
5. reboot

It loads the boot menu from my device. In other words, the only way to "find" the nvme controller again is if I open the UEFI settings and then reboot again.

Note also: if I don't specify `panic=5`, the kernel panic occurs, and I hold the power button down to reboot, this doesn't happen. The automatic reboot as part of `panic=5` seems to be causing this.

- What would cause a kernel panic to result in the NVMe controller "disappearing"?
- What occurs while just entering the UEFI setup menu that would cause the NVMe controller to return again on the next reboot?